# Access subtract time

Tags: sql, ms-access, datetime, ms-access-2007

How can I subtract two times in an Access table?

query must do it automatically. I need to subtract left time with arrived, so then I get hours of working employed:

Query must fill hours column in table, so I can get it in c# program.

> [Left]- [Arrived]

[image: Image of table in Datasheet View]

Comment: Thank you for solutions(all of them works fine), but how can I make querry that access will automaticly calculate and show it in hours column?

Comment: I do not understud your new inquiry: do you want to UPDATE a field over the same table with the calculated result?  what do you mean with "show it in hours column"?

Comment: Yes I want to update "hours". In "hours" must be worked time. It must update(calculate "left"-"arrived") automaticly.

Comment: the best solution is to remove that field and offer allways a calculated result, just to avoid redundance. but if you want an update you can do: `UPDATE yourTable SET hours = cdbl([Left] - [Arrived]) * 24` and optionaly a where clause `WHERE hours is null` or something else

Comment: Also, you should be aware that this approach is not aware of daylight savings time changes. If you have employees that work overnight, or in the early morning hours, and if you are in a time zone that has DST, then twice a year, you might underpay or overpay your employees by as much as an hour.

Answer (score 4):

In access, if the fields are date/time type, it is as simple as substract them and format output as desired. The substraction results in days and fraction of days. If you want it in hours, just multiply by 24, which gives you, hours and fracition of hours

```
SELECT cdbl([Left] - [Arrived]) * 24 as worked_hours FROM yourtable
```

Comment: While `DateDiff` is a great function I like this better because `DateDiff` will truncate your hours. I'm sure OP's employees will appreciate being counted as working 7 hours when they worked 7:59 hours.

Comment: DateDiff will not truncate hours if you use seconds. See my post. This works too though.

Answer (score 1):

DateDiff

DateDiff ( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear])

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

DateDiff ("h", [Arrived], [Left])

Comment: If you want to do this through a table value (instead of a query) you can't use a Default Value. You must use a Calculated column. You're better off using a query.

Answer (score 0):

As Russell mentioned, use `DateDiff` function. I tested on a test MsAccess DB and it works. Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT DateDiff('n',[Arrived],[Left])/60 AS Worked, 
       DateDiff('s',[Arrived],[Left])/3600 AS Worked2, 
       *
FROM Table1;
```

Sample Results:

```
Worked               Worked2               Left                  Arrived
1                    0.999722222222222      4/9/2013 3:00:00 PM  4/9/2013 2:00:01 PM
0.833333333333333    0.833055555555556      4/9/2013 3:00:00 PM  4/9/2013 2:10:01 PM
1.66666666666667E-02 2.77777777777778E-04   4/9/2013 3:00:00 PM  4/9/2013 2:59:59 PM
24                   23.9997222222222       4/9/2013 3:00:00 PM  4/8/2013 3:00:01 PM
```

As you can see, the Worked2 approach (by second) is a bit more accurate.

Comment: I didn't think requirements were strict enough, but I've updated my post to accommodate this.